# Calculate value in API call and remember it across the whole request

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am looking for the best design to implement the following.
I have **ClassA** and **ClassB**
A method called MethodA in **ClassA** calls **MethodB1** in **ClassB**.
**MethodB1** is something like

```
public bool MethodB1()
{
    var x = ClassC.CalculateX();
    if(x)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //do something else;
    return true;
}
```

**MethodA** calls **MethodB1** only once.

There are other methods in **ClassB** that call **MethodB1** multiple times in a loop.

> Typically we have two scenarios:
>
> 1. API endpoint => MethodA => MethodB1 (here we know the value of x
>      that never changes in a single call) => MethodB2 => MethodB1 (called
>      multiple times in a loop)
> 2. API endpoint => MethodB2 => MethodB1 (called multiple times in a
>      loop and we will get the value of x that is not going to change in a
>      single call)

Getting the value of x is expensive operation, I want to do it once in the first scenario and remember it in the current call to be used in other places in ClassA and ClassB. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Pass it into the other method.

Comment: how about getting the value of x and save it to the receiver then place the value of x from the header of your next api calls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before returning the value of `x`, store it in a field in `ClassC`. If this field already has a value in it, just return the same from `CalculateX`.
2. Register `ClassC` as a Scoped service in your dependency injection container. This will make sure that you get the same instance of `ClassC` throughout a single request lifecycle.
3. Inject `ClassC` wherever needed and call `CalculateX`.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the same instance of ClassC in the request lifecycle. Could be the best solution!

Comment: Are you working on ASP.Net Core Web API? If not, which framework and DI container are you using? @Bedair